# How to override SYS variable in Exstream

Tags: opentext, hpx, hp-exstream

I want to override system variable while running the application. Is there way to override SYS variable in page using control file VARSET.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on which system variable you are referring to.

It is possible to define a very small subset of system variables via a VARSET in a control file, eg: SYS_LanguageCustomer, SYS_LocaleCustomer.

The documentation also refers to system variables that you can calculate within a rule or a formula.

It is also possible to set some system variables via a data file mapping, eg initialization, reference, customer data file.

If you cannot set the system variable via VARSET, may want to attempt one of the alternative methods.